# How to pass object array to React Component in HTML File

Tags: html, dom, reactjs

my english is very basic (I am sorry).

I need help to rendering app with golang in my html file.

My structure file is:

```
- app
  /dist
     - bundle.js
  /main
  /template
     - index.html
     - index.js
     /js/Component.js
```

Ok... now I will explain my problem...

My html file contains.

```
<script type="text/babel">
 jQuery("document").ready(function(){
 jQuery("#sent-btn").click(function(ev){
   var data_json = {};
   data_json['w'] = jQuery("#w").val();
   data_json['r'] = jQuery("#r").val();
   $.ajax({
         type: 'post',
         url: 'investigate',
         data: JSON.stringify(data_json),
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         traditional: true,
         success: function(data) {
             var list = []
             for (var i = 0; i < data.Data.length; i++) {
               list.push({"name":data.Data[i].File , "email":data.Data[i].Quantity})
             }
             ReactDOM.render(<Component contacts=list />, getElementById("forms"))
             //ReactDOM.render(<ReactRouter.Router><ReactRouter.Route name="Component" path="" contacts={list} /> </ReactRouter.Router>, document.getElementById("forms"));
             //ReactDOM.render(< Component contacts={list} />, getElementById("forms"))
        }
        });
      });
    });
```

-> Index.js

Clarification :
I have too index.js that contains supposed javascript file to use my component and with webpack transform index.js to bundle.js

My index.js is:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

// Import component
import Component from './js/Component.js'
```

This situation is that into script I need send list to Component and I don't know.

I need to do something like comments but I can't, please help.

And Sorry for my english.

Comment: Why is your question tagged with `go`? Btw. please clarify your question to makes the things a little bit cleaner for us.

Comment: I'm no expert but React Components have a beautifull lifecycle, maybe you should use that instead of click event in JQuery

Comment: ok guys, my explication is ready, help me please